# How to handle child component from parent

Tags: reactjs

I was looking for some useful information how to handle parent component from child and found some piece of code, i understand everything in this code except one moment. So here is code

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function() {
    return {
      items: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    }
  },

  handleClick:function() {
    var newItem = this.refs.textRef.getDOMNode().value;
    var newItems = this.state.items.concat([newItem]);
    this.setState({
      items: newItems
    });
    this.refs.textRef.getDOMNode().value = "";
  },

  deleteItem:function(item) {
    var index = this.state.items.indexOf(item);
    var newItems = undefined;
    if (index > -1) {
      this.state.items.splice(index, 1);
      newItems = this.state.items;
      this.setState({
        items: newItems
      })
    };
  },

  render:function() {
    var item = this.state.items.map(function(item,i) {
      return <SubItem key={i} someText={item} onDelete={this.deleteItem}/>
    }.bind(this)); // dont understand
    return (<div>
              <input ref="textRef" type="text"/>
              <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
              {item}
            </div>)
  }
});

var SubItem = React.createClass({
  handleDelete:function() {
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.someText)
  },
  render:function() {
    return  (<ul>
              <li onClick={this.handleDelete}>{this.props.someText}</li>
            </ul>)
  }
})

React.render(<App />, document.body)
```

And i have broken my understanding about React on part inside  handleDelete function

```
handleDelete:function() {
        this.props.onDelete(this.props.someText)
      },
```

*What does it mean and how does it work ?* Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9714/) 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to the child component a callback, `deleteItem`.

The child component, when you click, triggers the `handleDelete` function, which triggers the `onDelete` callback, `deleteItem` in the parent.

This is a common pattern in React: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: Thank for this information, now my understanding a bit clearer

Answer (score 1):

- `this.props.onDelete` refer to `deleteItem` function of parent component.
- `this.props.someText` refer to `item` which is an element of your `items` state in this case [1,2,3,4..]

For example, `this.props.onDelete(1)` ( in case `this.props.someText` = 1 ). It actually calls the `deleteItem(1)` of the parent.

For `this.state.items.map(function(item,i)`, you can translate like this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
 {
    var item += <Subitem key={i} someText={items[i]} onDelete={this.deleteItem}/>
  }
```

If you want to understand the `bind(this)` part. Here is [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

I hope it will help you !!! :)

Comment: This  *this.state.items.map(function(item,i)* and *bind(this)* its easy to understand)) I cant undestand this chain, but anyway Thanks +1 for you